# ¿Cómo habilitar y de deshabilitar un curso?

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

como puedo hacer que al presionar un botón especifico se active y desactive el curso en mi base de datos, estoy manejando como un boolean, ESTE ES MI CODIGO

MODELO
'status_curso' es el que estoy manejando como boolean en mi base de datos

```
    class Curso extends Eloquent{
    protected $connection = 'mongodb';
    protected $collection = 'cursos';


    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nombre_curso',
        'nombre_periodo',
        'fecha_inicio_curso',
        'fecha_fin_curso',
        'status_curso',
        'resumen_curso',
        'descripcion_curso',
        'estudiantes'
    ];
}
```

VISTA
en la visto tengo los cards que muestran los cursos y quiero que al presionar el botón especifico para desactivar o activar me lo refleje en la base de datos.

```
    <div class="row">
<h1>Activos</h1>
<!--Card de mis cursos-->
@foreach($mis_cursos as $mi_curso)<!--Bucle para recorrer los cursos-->
@if($mi_curso->status_curso == true)
      @foreach($mi_curso->estudiantes as $est)<!--Bucle anidado para recorrer los estudiantes de un curso-->
          @if($est)<!--If para evitar errores en el Objeto "Cuando en el objecto no esta la estructura bien"-->
            @if($est['email'] == Auth::user()->email) <!--If que comprueba que el email dentro de estudiantes sea igual al email del auth-->
              <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 m-4" id="tooltip">
                <div class="card card-block p-4">
                
                  <h5 class="card-title mt-3 mb-3"> {{$mi_curso->nombre_curso}}</h5>
                  <span class="card-text lenguage">Inicio: {{$mi_curso->fecha_inicio_curso}}</span>
                  <span class="card-text">Fin: {{$mi_curso->fecha_fin_curso}}</span><br>
                  <span class="card-text">Resumen <br>{{$mi_curso->resumen_curso}}</span>
                  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                  <p></p>
                  <a href="{{route('verCurso',$mi_curso->_id)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">ver curso</a>
                  <br>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Desactivar</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">activar</button>
                      
                      <br>
                     
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            @endif
          @endif
          
      @endforeach
      @endif
@endforeach
</div>
```

CONTROLADOR
no se si manejar una función dividida o una sola función para los dos.

```
    public function index($periodoSeleccionado = "")
    {       
            $cursos = Curso::where('nombre_periodo', $periodoSeleccionado)->get();
            $temas = Tema::all();
            $periodos = Periodo::all();
            $actividades = Actividad::all();
            $mis_cursos = Curso::all();

            return view('homeDocente',compact('cursos', 'periodos','periodoSeleccionado', 'temas', 'actividades', 'mis_cursos'));
    }
```

Comment: ¿Por qué la etiqueta de mongodb?

Comment: Por otro lado ¿con un update no alcanza para lo que buscas?

Comment: La etiqueta es para conectarme a mi base de datos, estoy utilizando Mongo Atlas
Y si con el update, pero no se si hacerlo por separado

Comment: Ok, aunque el ORM no esta pensado precisamente para el trabajo con bases de datos no relacionales, por otro lado vuelvo a mi segunda pregunta ¿no alcanza con un update?

Comment: Entonces la pregunta se vuelve confusa @pedro ya que no queda claro si no sabes hacer el update o que necesitas

Comment: si, no se como realizar el update

Comment: Entonces edita tu pregunta por favor y agrega lo que tenga que ver únicamente con la actualización, por cierto puedes empezar por aqui: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/